# Checking package status

Tags: packages

I want to know if I have a package installed. Like it says [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages#Checking_package_status) I write:

```
root@linux:~# kpsewhich koma-script
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: `kpsewhich` is for finding _files_, not package names, so you'd have to do `kpsewhich scrbook.cls` or similar. Or use `tlmgr info koma-script` and inspect the output. (It has an "installed" field.)

Comment: I downloaded the scrbook.cls file to a local directory but I only get `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls`

Comment: Also: I wouldn't use the root account for such "menial" tasks as writing LaTeX documents/packages/classes. ;-)

Comment: I was installing koma-script, just forgot to exit.

Comment: why would you do that (download to some directory)? Just install it the normal way: `tlmgr install koma-script`. Anyway, if you did want to install manually, it has to be placed in a location searched by TeX to be found. And please rename it to avoid licensing problems and conflicts with officially-distributed packages. Please see [Where do I place my own `.sty` or `.cls` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)

Comment: Because I'm getting weird messages ! LaTeX Error: File `typearea.sty' not found.   user@linux:~/libro/principal$ kpsewhich typearea.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty

Comment: Seems like a classic case of two TeX installations: did you install TeX Live via your linux distro's package manager and then try installing Vanilla TeX Live? If that's the case (or vice versa) you need to eliminate the one you don't want.

Comment: Oh I thought I had removed it. But I'm sure that is the problem.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu. (Can be adapted for other distros if you are not on a Debian derivative.)

Comment: You are aware that `scrbook` is not enough, it loads quite a bunch of helper files/packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an answer to the question rather than the problem (which has been identified in comments).

To check the installation status of a package and to get additional information about it, execute the following as yourself. (Certainly no need for root privileges here.)

```
$ tlmgr info koma-script
```

On my system, this gives:

```
package:     koma-script
category:    TLCore
shortdesc:   A bundle of versatile classes and packages
longdesc:    The KOMA-Script bundle provides replacements for the article, report, and book classes with emphasis on typography and versatility. There is also a letter class. The bundle also offers: a package for calculating type areas in the way laid down by the typographer Jan Tschichold, a package for easily changing and defining page styles, a package scrdate for getting not only the current date but also the name of the day, and a package scrtime for getting the current time. All these packages may be used not only with KOMA-Script classes but also with the standard classes. Since every package has its own version number, the version number quoted only refers to the version of scrbook, scrreprt, scrartcl, scrlttr2 and typearea (which are the main parts of the bundle).
installed:   Yes
revision:    36095
sizes:       run: 18785k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 3.15
cat-date:    2015-01-18 21:13:21 +0100
cat-license: lppl1.3
collection:  collection-latexrecommended
```

Comment: I thought there was surely a duplicate, but I can't find one and you've already answered it. :-)

Comment: so the command I provided does nothing?

Comment: @Arturo I already explained in my comment: `kpsewhich` searches for _files_ not package names. Because the `koma-script` package/bundle doesn't contain a file called `koma-script`, `kpsewhich koma-script` will return nothing because there's nothing to return...

Comment: @PaulGessler It is worse than that. I thought I'd already answered a question like this... ;) You solved the problem, anyway. By rights, the green tick should be yours!